# Experiences with AD9826 serial communication

Tags: microcontroller, adc, spi, tm4c123g

I try to establish a communication with the [TM4C123GXL](https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C123GXL?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=epd-null-null-OPN_EN-cpc-evm-google-eu&utm_content=Device_ToolFolder&ds_k=EK-TM4C123GXL&DCM=yes&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItvT73Km18wIVGKp3Ch1mDwC4EAAYASAAEgJFFfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and the [AD9826](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9826.pdf).
For the communication I use the SPI interface of the TM4C123GXL. The SSI Rx and Tx are connected via a 3 kOhm resistor.

The AD9826 requires the following timings.
[image: Serial Read Operation Timing AD9826]

With the SPI peripheral from TM4C123GXL I generated the following timings, where ***blue = clock, turquoise = data and purple = sload***

[image: Tektronix DPO3034 Screenshot]

Unfortunately I do not get a response from the AD9826 or rather it is wrong. I try to read the content of the configuration register which has the address 0x000. So by adding the address bit it would be 0x1000000. The response which I expect would be 11111000 - which is the default value for the configuration register.

So this raises the following questions to me.

1. Does the AD9826 need a continuous clock? (This would be a problem, as the TM4C123GXL SPI peripheral cannot provide it).
2. Is this three wire "SPI" a SPI kind of communication? (For me it looks like the MICROWIRE frame format)
3. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
4. Is the read bit high or low? I assumed that it is high from the picture below. There is no further indication in the datasheet.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Justme* is right. The first bit of the data signal must be shifted to the left, so that it aligns with the first clock pulse.

After some investigations I can answer the following.

1. Does the AD9826 need a continuous clock? (This would be a problem, as the TM4C123GXL SPI peripheral cannot provide it).

Serial clock can be turned off if no read or write operation is done. (see [Analog Devices Engineering Zone](https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/high-speed_adcs/f/q-a/21018/ad9826-serial-config-clock-disable))

2. Is this three wire "SPI" a SPI kind of communication? (For me it looks like the MICROWIRE frame format)

For the TM4C123GXL the Motorola Freescale Frame Format must be used (see initialization code below)

```
        SSI2_CR1_R &= ~SSI_CR1_SSE;
        SSI2_CC_R = 0; // using system main clock
        SSI2_CR0_R |= (scaler<<SSI_CR0_SCR_S); 
        SSI2_CPSR_R |= clkDivider;
        SSI2_CR0_R |=  SSI_CR0_FRF_MOTO; // Motorola Freescale Frame Format
        SSI2_CR0_R |= SSI_CR0_DSS_16; // 16 Bit data
        SSI2_CR1_R |= SSI_CR1_SSE;
```

1. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

   Apart from setting the bit on the wrong position, I selected the wrong frame format.
2. Is the read bit high or low? I assumed that it is high from the picture below. There is no further indication in the datasheet.

   Read bit is high.

In addition I can share the following outcomes.

- Default values are not guaranteed during power up (see [ADI Engineering Zone](https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/high-speed_adcs/f/q-a/534031/ad9826-operation))
- It is not recommended to burst the clock signal of the ADC itself (ADCCLK, CDSCLK1, CDSCLK2, see [ADI Engineering Zone](https://ez.analog.com/cn/support-reference-library/dds/f/forum-499704002/52785/the-use-of-ad9826))

Answer (score 1):

There is a mixup in the addressing of read and write operations.

The first bit is the R/Wb bit and it is low so you are doing a serial write operation to address 100 in binary. For a read operation the R/Wb bit would be high.

Comment: Thanks,  unfortunately it still does not work. Is it by convention that the write bit is usually one and the read bit is usually zero? I extended my question regarding the write and read bit.

Comment: @Johannes According to what convention? There is no convention. The chip datasheet just says this chip works like this. Read is high, write low.

Comment: you're right. I shifted the bit and it looks good now. thx